# How to decide which of two "linked" objects should be contained in the other?

Tags: object-oriented-design

Are there any guiding principles of OO design to take into account when deciding which of two interacting and linked objects should be included as a component into the other (or referenced from it)?

For example, I am trying to realise the A* shortest path search algorithm with classes and objects.  Besides a given graph, I plan to have a `DataFlow` object and a `Controller` object.  I plan the `DataFlow` object to be responsible for maintaining the state of knowledge about the shortest paths found so far and for propagating improvements from nodes to their neighbours.  I plan the `Controller` object to be responsible for the graph exploration strategy and to make it configurable with any of a number of strategies (A*, Dijkstra, greedy, etc.).

After some thought, I've decided that the `DataFlow` object is going to receive and store the `Controller` object during initialisation, but I cannot explain clearly why this would be better than the other way around.

Comment: Perhaps you can start by choosing names that better reflect responsibilities, such as `ShortestPaths' and `PathFinder` (or `ExplorationStrategy').

Comment: How are these objects interacting?  That would seem to be the most important thing here.

Comment: @Marco, IMO my names reflect the responsibilities better (the Controller is more than  a strategy, the DataFlow object does not manipulate paths, etc.)  The choice of names is in any case irrelevant.

Comment: @JimmyJames, they will obviously interact slightly differently depending on which one will be calling methods of the other.  `DataFlow` does not care where to go next and which updated node to treat next by updating its neighbours.  `Controller` keeps only as much information as necessary to be able to tell the `DataFlow` where to go next.  So, the `Controller` controls the `DataFlow`, but it can either send messages and receive, or receive and send.

Comment: If Controller is controlling the DataFlow, it would seem that the obvious (possibly naïve) solution is to have the Controller keep a reference to the DataFlow.  How do you plan to have the Controller send messages to the DataFlow in your current thinking?

Comment: Well, calling and returning is "dual" to returning and calling: the `DataFlow` will be asking the `Controller` what to do next.  It seemed to me that there are some things that can be optimised for speed in `DataFlow` if its methods do not have to return often.  When a method returns, it loses all locale variables and local data structures...

Comment: "When a method returns, it loses all locale variables and local data structures": Sure but you could always store whatever that is at an object level.  I'm not saying that's the right answer, just trying to understand the design.  I think I understand though.  The DataFlow is doing some work and then telling the Controller it's results and getting it's next task, right?

Comment: Yes, that is exact.  Storing temporary data on object level has some extra overhead and is a bit problematic because when a method returns, it does not know if and when it will be called next time, and whether any other methods will be called in between. Anyway, in my current design the `Controller` is going to keep its data on the object level while the `DataFlow` has the control.

Comment: "The choice of names is in any case irrelevant" - absolutely disagree. If you have a clear understanding of responsibilities, good names often follow naturally. Conversely, un-informative names like "Controller" frequently betray confused thinking about the named object. You _could_ understand perfectly and _choose_ a terrible name deliberately, but I suspect you don't know what to call your things because you haven't decided what they are.

Comment: @Useless, the choice of names in my example is irrelevant to my question. Call them `X` and `Y`.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of OO methodology, I don't believe there's a guideline about which way a reference between objects should point.  This is something that is derived as part of the design process i.e. form follows function.  In OO methodologies, there are names for these different options and that can assist with the design process.

In UML, for example you have the idea of associations.  These can be categorized into aggregations or compositions.  These are basically the same with the key difference of whether the associated objects are 'part' of the object that references them (composition) or whether they exist independently (aggregation).

As far as the design goes, it seems reasonable.  It strikes me a similar to using generators in Python as a communication channel (using `send()`).  With the approach you are taking the direction of the reference seems to be correct.